# C# UDP listener un-blocking? or prevent revceiving from being stuck

Tags: c#, udp

I've been searching for previous problems like mine here but it seems I can't find the answer I need.

My goal is to prevent my UDP listener from not hanging. I have a UDP listener who waits for messages but if there is nothing to receive it just hangs there.

I have read other threads and they say that I need to set the **Blocking to false** but I can't find how to set it. Sorry I'm just new to C# and to socket programming.

Here's the part of my listener:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

        IPEndPoint newuser = new IPEndPoint(groupEP.Address, groupEP.Port);
        string sData =  (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is it just freezes on the following line:

```
byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the available property on the UDPClient (if this is what you are using) to determine if you have data in the network queue to read.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        if (listener.Available > 0) // Only read if we have some data 
        {                           // queued in the network buffer. 
            byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

            IPEndPoint newuser = new IPEndPoint(groupEP.Address, groupEP.Port);
            string sData =  (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But then, without any loop break, doesnt it actually amount to same as original code ? it is good to block at Receive() rather than burning CPU with continuous if(available) checks in the loop , isnt it ?

Comment: Add a `Thread.Sleep(10);` inside `try{}` clause and CPU burning is gone completely..

Comment: this post saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

```
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        //Some code goes here ...
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 2000);
```

//This is pretty clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the blocking versions of Receive/Send. Consider using the async versions (ReceiveAsync/BeginReceive) instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The linked page says: The Receive method blocks execution until a message is received which is exactly what the question is trying to avoid

Comment: That's why I said they should use the ASYNC versions. ReceiveAsync Remarks: "This operation will not block. "

Answer (score 0):

```
TestHost.Client.Blocking = false;
```

You need to access the 'Socket' object, beneath the UdpClient object ('TestHost' in the detailed example below), to get to the 'Blocking' property as shown:

```
int Port = 9020;    //Any port number you like will do
IPAddress ActiveIPaddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 3, 10 }); //Any IPaddress you need will do
IPEndPoint HostEP = new IPEndPoint(ActiveIPaddress, Port);
UdpClient TestHost = new UdpClient(Global.HostEP);
TestHost.Client.Blocking = false;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSGir.png)