# How can I make every client be aware of every other client connected to the same UDP network?

Tags: c#, udp

I would like every client to 'be aware of' every other client that has connected within the UDP network at request.

So far I have a very simple program where every client inputs a username and sends it to the network. Every client stores a list of usernames to keep track of who has communicated with the network at least once. If a new username pops in, it outputs it to the console and stores it in the list as to prevent from outputting it again.

This is all fine and dandy but I've only managed the above by having every client continuously awaiting new data from the network (because it can never know when new clients will stop 'entering' the network).

Here's all the code. The part of interest is probably the displayAllUsers() function.

I've pasted the whole program because it is (i) very short (ii) my knowledge of UDP within C# is very green, and my practices are in no way good, so maybe it is a good idea to have readers be aware of that.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Node
{
    class Program
    {

        static UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        static IPEndPoint localIP;
        static IPEndPoint remoteIP;

        static String currentUser;
        static List<String> currentUsers = new List<String>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            initialiseListener();
            initialiseWriter();

            Console.WriteLine("What's your username?");
            currentUser = Console.ReadLine();
            Byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentUser);
            //Who is current user?

            client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, remoteIP);

            Console.WriteLine("Here are all active users:");


            displayAllUsers();


        }

        private static void displayAllUsers()
        {
            Byte[] buffer;

            while (true)
            {


                Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localIP); //blocking call - continuously listening 
                string strData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);


                if (!currentUsers.Contains(strData)) //if data is not found in current users list...
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(strData); //write username on screen
                    currentUsers.Add(strData); //and add to current users list

                    buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentUser); //Convert currentUser to bytes
                    client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, remoteIP); //and send new current user to everyone else
                }


            }

        }

        private static void initialiseWriter()
        {
            IPAddress multicastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");
            client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddress);
            //Send data to this multicast address group

            remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(multicastAddress, 2222); //To write to the multicastAddress group on port 2222
        }

        private static void initialiseListener()
        {
            client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
            //More than one client can use the port to be specified

            localIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2222); //To listen on any IP Address available from the port 2222

            client.Client.Bind(localIP); //Associate client with listener
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, each client would be able to request the displayAllUsers() device whenever and have such list generated for them, rather than constantly awaiting new clients to join in.

Eventually I'd like to implement my knowledge of UDP and non-centralized networking to an Xamarin app and have every device be aware of every other device that has such app open.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use UDP for this? Your "ideally" section describes a centralized approach, maybe a Web API... Certainly not UDP.

Comment: @CoolBots: I've tried implementing UDP as to prevent turning on a server (or a web API) just to have the app work. I'd like the app to allow the device it's on to communicate with other devices without making use of a centralized entity. But I'm not exactly sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Web API can be setup on the same machine or local network for development purposes; it can also be hosted free of charge on Azure (limitations apply to free hosting). UDP is pretty much not routable outside of your local network - your app won't work over internet. If you're developing for intranet use only, UDP is ok for quick notifications that you can afford to miss, or receive out of order (its a terrible protocol, with no error correction or delivery guarantees); it isn't  suitable for anything else. Used to be popular in gaming, due to speed; even that's not the case anymore. Avoid it.

Comment: @CoolBots: That's the thing though, I don't want it to work over the internet. My main requirement is just to have devices be aware of each other that are within the same network. I'll have a look at your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, there's really nothing wrong with using a Multicast UDP for **local discovery**. Plenty of industrial control systems out there use the same functionality. Not everything needs to be Web-this-or-another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932204/c-sharp-udp-listener-un-blocking-or-prevent-revceiving-from-being-stuck) and modified the below in my displayAllUsers() method.

```
if(client.Available > 0){
   data = client.Receive(ref localIP); //blocking call - continuously listening 
}else{
   break;
}
```

Using the .Available property proved to be very useful as it checks if there is something to listen to -- just what I needed.

I will mark this as the thread's answer if it is found to be good practice.